# Python socket - Provide user credentials when connecting

Tags: python, sockets, web

I have one Python script, which uses to connect to Google. I am using it in my workplace and currently, they changed our network. Now, every time i want to open Google or some other external website, I need to enter my credentials. And now my script does not work. I get an error, stating that I am not able to connect.

My question is: Is there any way to provide my credential with the script, when connecting? I looked at the socket library's function, but I couldn't find any function, doing so. Is this possible at all?

Thanks,

**EDIT:** Here is some extra information:
I am using the **socket** library. I have the following piece of code:

```
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
s.connect(("google.com", 80))
self.ip = s.getsockname()[0]
s.close()
```

I need to connect to a proxy server.

Comment: what have you done. Which lib? Don't expect spoon feeding please

Comment: To provide credentials to what exactly? Proxy server? Or something else?

Comment: I have added some extra information.